# How to know if mediatek vcom drivers is installed on my pc

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, usb-drivers, mediatek

I've just installed mediatek vcom driver on my pc, to use it in flashing mediatek based firmwares. But is there any way I can know if it truly installed on my pc without plugging a mediatek phone for recognition, maybe through control panel or device manager or somewhere else please.

Comment: it's not the driver that will installed, it's the device that will installed with correct drivers